# Same input giving different output when getting values in Flask template vs frontend

Tags: python, angular, flask, postman, flask-restful

I got a function in my `app.py` which returns a value as output. When I'm getting the output from flask template by using `render_template('index.html',prediction_text="Sell at: "{}".format(output))` it is returning the output as **6.64 which is the expected value**. But now instead of rendering the data in flask template I'm using a frontend application Angular 9 to render the response, so from Angular 9 I'm sending the input as form-data to the server and the server now needs to send the response back to Angular in json format thus using `json.dumps(output)`.

But in doing so I'm now getting **9.58** as output instead of **6.64** while the inputs still remain the same. When trying from postman also the output is coming as **9.58** when sending data as form-data. Here is the github link of the project: https://github.com/krishnaik06/Car-Price-Prediction
I'm relatively new in Flask and python so any help will be appreciated.

app.py

```
standard_to = StandardScaler()
@app.route("/predict", methods=['POST','GET'])
def predict():
    Fuel_Type_Diesel=0
    if request.method == 'POST':
        Year = int(request.form['Year'])
        Present_Price=float(request.form['Present_Price'])
        Kms_Driven=int(request.form['Kms_Driven'])
        Kms_Driven2=np.log(Kms_Driven)
        Owner=int(request.form['Owner'])
        Fuel_Type_Petrol=request.form['Fuel_Type_Petrol']
        if(Fuel_Type_Petrol=='Petrol'):
                Fuel_Type_Petrol=1
                Fuel_Type_Diesel=0
        else:
            Fuel_Type_Petrol=0
            Fuel_Type_Diesel=1
        Year=2020-Year
        Seller_Type_Individual=request.form['Seller_Type_Individual']
        if(Seller_Type_Individual=='Individual'):
            Seller_Type_Individual=1
        else:
            Seller_Type_Individual=0    
        Transmission_Manual=request.form['Transmission_Manual']
        if(Transmission_Manual=='Manual'):
            Transmission_Manual=1
        else:
            Transmission_Manual=0
        prediction=model.predict([[Present_Price,Kms_Driven2,Owner,Year,Fuel_Type_Diesel,Fuel_Type_Petrol,Seller_Type_Individual,Transmission_Manual]])
        output=round(prediction[0],2)
        if output<0:
            return render_template('index.html',prediction_texts="Sorry you cannot sell this car")
        else:
           # return render_template('index.html',prediction_text="You Can Sell The Car at {}".format(output))   # Getting 6.64 as output
            return json.dumps(output)    # Getting 9.58 as output
    else:
        return render_template('index.html')

if __name__=="__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

[image: Postman Snippet]